# Showing Error Segmentation fault

Tags: c

This code is of Stack Using Double Linked list. This Code works fine except for one condition i.e whenever the last node is deleted it shows 'Segmentation fault' error!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_type{
    int value;
    struct node_type *next, *prev;
}node;

node *insert(int value, node *top){
    node *p;
    p = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if(top == NULL){
        top = p;
        p -> value = value;
        p -> next = NULL;
        p -> prev = NULL;
        return top;
    }
    else{
        p -> value = value;
        p -> next = top;
        p -> prev = NULL;
        top -> prev = p;
        top = p;
        return top;
    }
}

node *del(node *top){
    node *temp;
    if(top == NULL){
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
    }
    else{
        temp = top;
        top = top -> next;
        top -> prev = NULL;
        free(temp);
    }
    return top;
}

node *disp(node *top){  
    if(top == NULL){
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
    }
    else{
        while(top != NULL){
            printf("The value is: %d\n", top -> value);
            top = top->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int value, ch = 0;
    node *top = NULL;
    while( ch != 4){
        printf("------> 1. Insert  <-------\n");
        printf("------> 2. Delete  <-------\n");
        printf("------> 3. Display <-------\n");
        printf("------> 4.  Exit   <-------\n");
        printf("Enter the choice\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch){
            case 1:
                printf("Enter the value\n");
                scanf("%d",&value);
                top = insert(value, top);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Removing the element\n");
                top = del(top);
                break;
            case 3:
                disp(top);
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong Choice\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the last node of a linked list is a special case, you need special code to handle it.

Comment: specifically, dont do `top -> prev = NULL;` if `top` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your del function. If it is a last node top->next will be NULL.
In your code

> top = top->next;

makes top NULL. then you are trying

> top->prev = NULL;

which is equal to dereferencing a NULL pointer and that is the problem.
You wil have to handle this in else part.
like

> if(top->next == NULL)
>   free top;

and thats will solve the prblem.